# Is SpringData's DomainClassConverter supposed to work with Hibernate proxies?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, thymeleaf

My team maintains a web app built with Spring Boot, Spring Data, Thymeleaf, and JPA/Hibernate. We recently hit an issue with a Thymeleaf template SpringEL expression failing to evaluate due to a type conversion problem:

> Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [com.xyz.app.model.Employee_$$_jvst7ca_34] to type [java.lang.String]

The expression is ${{employee}} where employee is an entity placed into the model by a Spring controller. The employee entity is retrieved with a simple call to a Spring Data repository:

```
@ModelAttribute("employee")
public Employee getEmployee(@PathVariable("employeeId") long employeeId) {
    return employeeRepository.findOne(employeeId);
}
```

While debugging, I noticed that the Employee entity returned is actually a Hibernate proxy, as you can see in the exception cause from the log - the Employee class has the javassist suffix: `_$$_jvst7ca_34`

Spring Data registers `DomainClassConverter` with Spring's `GenericConversionService` which should convert an entity to an ID for an expression like ${{employee}} when the `@EnableSpringDataWebSupport` annotation is present.  Spring Boot provides an autoconfiguration class `SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration` which enables this by default. I confirmed that this autoconfiguration class is applied by our application.

I also confirmed through debugging that the `GenericConversionService` retrieves the `DomainClassConverter.ToIdConverter` when attempting to convert from Employee_$$_jvst7ca_34 to String. However `DomainClassConverter.ToIdConverter.matches(sourceType, targetType)` returns false, so the converter is not used. It returns false because it cannot find a repository in `Repositories` with the type `Employee_$$_jvst7ca_34`. I see with the debugger that the only Employee repository in the Repositories list is for `Employee`.

Is this a bug in `DomainClassConverter`? Shouldn't it be capable of retrieving a repository for a proxy? It seems that proxies should be quite common since any entity with a lazy collection (the recommended collection type) will come back as a proxy.  Or are we doing something wrong?  Any hints would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was a bug in Spring Data Commons. The [issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1215?jql=project%20%3D%20DATACMNS%20ORDER%20BY%20created%20DESC) has now been addressed and in future releases it should be possible to convert a proxy.